# is there a faster way to calculate electric fields due to nearby charges?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, scientific-computing

I need to calculate the electric field due to charges within some (small) distance of a site. Right now, my code loops over all charges and positions, calculates the position of each charge, and checks if the distance from the site is within the cutoff, and if so, it includes the corresponding charge in the electric field (n^2 for all n particles). To make this faster in one dimension, I could simply pre-sort (n*logn) the distances and loop over them until the distance > cutoff, and then break. I wonder if there is a way to do this in three dimensions and make the code many times faster. I'm a scientist, not a CS professional, so I may simply not know which data structure and/or algorithm is best for this kind of thing. Please enlighten me.

Thank you!

Comment: A good suggestion might be to look at k-nearest-neighbour classifiers which are often used in machine learning. Multiple approaches exist.

However, the fastest approaches approximate the solution.


See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Space_partitioning

Comment: Is the electric field changing constantly, or is it static? If static, or mostly static, there are many hierarchical acceleration structures you can use.

Comment: it is constantly changing and the calculation has to be exact every time...I tried some data structures from the freud analysis library but querying them is actually much slower than my brute force cython code...

Comment: For one site, your naive algorithm should be `O(n)`.  (`O(1)` work for each of `n` particles.)  Are you actually doing this calculation for `O(n)` sites?

Comment: if you have a lot of charges then use BVH structure. If you have small space or spatial precision You can do its VOXEL map and render the field value directly into it as "filled" sphere around each charge added to already rendered voxels ... and forget about BVH completely. This will lead to `O(n*r^3)` where `r` is the max distance your charge has any effect in [voxels]. This is also suited if you want to know the field value at many or all places